# Intuition on Connectedness and Clopen Sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, connectedness

In Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis, connectedness is defined in terms of clopen sets ; that a set is disconnected if it has proper clopen subsets.

In my mind, when I think of connectedness, I consider if there exists a continuous function from my set X to the discrete space {0,1} which is constant. If the function is not constant , some elements are mapped to 0 and some to 1 ; hence I get an intuitive idea whether X is disconnected.

In terms of clopen sets, my intuition is close to 0 ; I am fine with the formalism but it still doesn't "click".

I am basically looking for a "to-the-grandma" explanation. Apologies if any error committed.

Comment: You mean a function which is not constant? It's always true that constant functions exist.

Answer (score 0):

A space that is disconnected is the union of some disjoint connected open sets (since it's complement is also open, it's clopen). I think this is an easier way to think about that.

Take for example the space $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ with the quotient topology from $\mathbb{R}$ (open sets of $X$ are the sets that are of the form $X\cap U$ for $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ open). So the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ are both open, and are the connected components of $X$.

Edit: Note that your definition using the discrete space (a space $X$ is disconnected if there exists a non-constant continuous map from $X\to \{0,1\}$ as part of the discrete space) corresponds to this definition:

The inverse images of $0$ and $1$ are non-trivial clopen sets (your map is continuous and $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are both clopen).

Conversly: if you have two non-trivial clopen sets $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that $X_1\cup X_2=X$, than the map sending every point of $X_1$ to $0$ and every point of $X_2$ to $1$ is continuous.

Comment: Note also that connectedness is not the same as path connectedness and probably the more intuïtive notion you have about connectedness is actually path connectedness.